# How to display users text in the Validation Summary in MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

If I have a regular expression model validator set that displays an error if they type a letter when they are supposed to type an integer.  Is there a built in way to display the text the user enters inside the validation summary?

for instance if the user types "ab" can my validation message have a way to say;

You cannot enter "ab" for this field.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no _built in way_. You can only use static content in validation attributes (for `[RegularExpression]` attribute you have access to the property name and the regex string only). You can build your own message for server side validation as Bosman as indicated, but you cant do it for unobtrusive client side validation (unless maybe you were to handle the keyup event of the control to remove the validator, add a new adaptor with an error message based on the controls value, and parse the form again)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you would have to do custom validation in your controller to display a custom message. You could implement a [custom validation attribute](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx/) but a simple approach is as follow:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    int parse;

    if(!Int32.TryParse(model.value, out parse)
        ViewBag.Error = String.Format("You cannot enter \"{0}\" for this field", model.value);

    return View(model);
}
```

Alternatively you could add a custom error to the ModelState Error collection. More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)